# Expectation of Gaussian Ratios

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, discrete-mathematics

Consider the following expression: $z = \frac{\mathbf{x}^H P \mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^H \mathbf{y}}$, where $\mathbf{y}$ is fixed (not random) and $\mathbf{x}$ is a complex Gaussian vector of zero mean and covariance $\sigma^2 \mathbf{I}$. Finally matrix $P$ is idempotent, Hermitian, and Positive Semi Definite.

P.S: I know that the numerator $\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathbf{x}^H P \mathbf{x}$ is Chi-square distributed with $rank(P)$ degrees of freedom. The denominator $\mathbf{x}^H \mathbf{y}$ is Gaussian zero mean and variance $\Vert \mathbf{y} \Vert^2 \sigma^2$. I have ran simulations, and i get something like this for some $P$ and $\mathbf{y}$ : [image: Histogram of real part of z]

and

[image: Histogram of imaginary part of z]

Does anybody know how to compute the mean and variance of $z$ ?

Thanks a lot in advance.